# how to resolve the segmentation fault error in the given c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

this is a program to find the maximum occurrence of the largest number in an array.
how to resolve the segmentation fault error in this?  hackerrank problem

```
 /* given:
 1<n<10^5
 1<arrayNum[n] <10^7 */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
signed long int max,n,d,a,arrayNum[n]; 
signed long int  max_count; scanf("%ld",&n);
for( a=0; a < n; a++)
    {   

       scanf("%ld",&arrayNum[a]);
    }


max = arrayNum[0];
max_count = 1;
for (int a = 0; a < n; ++a)
{
    if (arrayNum[a] == max)
      max_count++;
    else if (arrayNum[a] > max)
   {
       max_count = 1;
       max = arrayNum[a];
   }
   }d=max_count;
   printf("%ld",d);
     return 0;}
```

Comment: Start by learning C. What do you think this line is doing? `signed long int max,n,d,a,arrayNum[n]; `

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
  signed long int max,n,d,a,arrayNum[n];  //<< the problem is here,
                                          //   the content of n is indeterminate
                                          //   at that state
  signed long int  max_count; scanf("%ld",&n);
  ...
```

`arrayNum[n]` is declared *before* the value of `n` is entered by the user.

Just change your code to something like that:

```
int main(){
  signed long int max,n,d,a;
  signed long int max_count;

  scanf("%ld",&n);
  signed long arrayNum[n];
  ...
```

There may be other issues though.

And as already stated by others: fix the code indentation. Correctly indentend/formatted code is essential so your code can be understood by others (and even more important by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a segmentation fault, the best way is to:

1. Understand what you do (do you really get what each line of your program does ?).
2. Fix the errors and warnings given by the compiler.
3. Compile with debug symbols (`-g` or `-g3`) and use a debugger (**gdb** for example) to find where is your segmentation fault.

Comment: This is better suited for comment not answer.

Comment: I agree this would be better suited for comment if the question was something like "why does it crash" or "where is my segfault". But the question here is "how to resolve the segfault ?". Following those steps will resolve the segfault. That was I decided to post it as an answer (but it was a touchy choice).

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your code indentation, make it more clear for us to read.

Then, give us more information about your segfault : where does it occurs ? You can use tools like Valgrind (on Linux) to find this kind of informations. You just have to build your program with debugging flags (-g on GCC) and run the program with GCC.

The problem here is `arrayNum[n]` which have the size of a non-initialized variable (n). So this array does not have any allocated space. The access to `arrayNum` through `scanf()` create this segfault.